# ML REST API Development Approach Comparison

Tags: marklogic

Many of my Marklogic custom modules / functions is about document transformation.
It could be done via either

1. [REST API Extension development](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/transforms) or
2. [Data Services](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/DataServices)

The difference between those two is mainly about whether it is used to build downstream app proxy wrapper library for Java / .NET / NodeJS. It is explained in that [Advantage of Data Service section](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/DataServices#id_34518)

However, it seems that there is 3rd way of doing it. It is via [REST API Transform](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/transforms)

Questions:

1. Am I right for REST API Transform as the 3rd implementation apprach?
2. The difference between **REST API Transform** is that it will require some "installation". It could not auto deployed via ML Gradle. In contrast, the other two could be deployed via ML Gradle mlDeploy. Is this correct?
3. When to use **REST API Transform**? Please give some comparisons between those three ML custom feature implementation approaches.

Comment: A 4th option is to just invoke an installed module directly, not as a REST extension. If overhead of REST rewriter is a concern and you don't care about generating client stubs from Data Services.

Comment: Matt. is the **installed module** you talked about just some local server side script pre-deployed to ML via mlGradle? if it is not, may I have the link to study it in detail?

Comment: REST transforms are loaded by ml-gradle as well - see https://github.com/marklogic/ml-gradle/wiki/How-modules-are-loaded . Just toss them under src/main/ml-modules/transforms.

Comment: Yes, an installed module is just code deployed to the modules db of the app server: https://developer.marklogic.com/learn/get-started-apps-2/